# MSB6006 in VisualStudio when using opencv VideoCapture

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm trying to capture frames from a video with opencv in VisualStudio but I run into the "MSB6006 : "CL.exe" exit code 2" error and I don't really understand what can be the problem. Can anyone help me here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    cv::VideoCapture cap("test.MOV");

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "Cannot open the video file.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    for (int frame_count = 0; frame_count < cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); frame_count++) {
        cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_count);
        cv::Mat frame;

        if (!cap.read(frame)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to extract a frame.\n";
            return -1;
        }

        std::string image_path = "frames/" + std::to_string(frame_count) + ".jpg";
        cv::imwrite(image_path, frame);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There should be a more detailed error message somewhere on the output window.

Comment: This code works fine for me. I'm unable to replicate your error. Perhaps your Visual Studio needs to be updated?